# TabView with different TabBar backgroundColor on each Tab SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, design-patterns, swiftui

I can't seem to get this simple problem working. I have a TabView with multiple Tabs, where depending on the selectedTab, the TabBar should have a different background. It should look like this, but this won't work, any help would be highly appreciated:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
   NavigationView{
      Home()
   }
   .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
   .tabItem{
            Image(systemName: "house")
   }.tag("home")
   .onAppear{
       UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
   }
    

   NavigationView{
      Post()
   }
   .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
   .tabItem{
            Image(systemName: "plus")
   }.tag("plus")
   .onAppear{
       UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
   }
}
```

Comment: `.toolbarBackground` is available in iOS 16 it should be in the App Store in the next week or 2. But is available in Beta now.

Comment: Thank you! But there is now way to make it possible for IOS 15?

Answer (score 0):

`.background()` method should do the trick. Would look something like this:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
    ZStack {
        Image(systemName: "house")
    }.tag("Home")
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
        .background(Color.red)
    
    ZStack {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }.tag("Plus")
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
        .background(Color.blue)
}.tabViewStyle(.page)
```

You can use any kind of container instead of the `ZStack`, or you could even apply the methods used on `ZStack`s directly to the images. Hope that helps!